# CLHeading magneticHeading will give different value if I change the way I hold the device

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I am using CLHeading's magneticHeading to get the heading direction of the device and it's quite accurate.

If I change the orientation of the device (screen facing x, y, or z axis), then magneticHeading's value will change ~ +- 15 degrees. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: not a programming question. this needs to be raised at a different community in stackexchange.

Comment: why is it not a programming question? I need to use some algorithm to adjust the magneticHeading value I got based on how I hold the device. If this is not considered a programming question, then any question related to "how to implement a step counter" is not considered a programming question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I admit that I'm no expert, but I suspect the [documentation for CLHeading](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLHeading_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLHeading/magneticHeading) will point you in the right direction (pun not intended)...

> The value in this property represents the heading relative to the magnetic North Pole, which is different from the geographic North Pole. The value 0 means the device is pointed toward magnetic north, 90 means it is pointed east, 180 means it is pointed south, and so on. The value in this property should always be valid.
>
> **In iOS 3.x and earlier, the value in this property is always measured relative to the top of the device in a portrait orientation, regardless of the device’s actual physical or interface orientation. In iOS 4.0 and later, the value is measured relative to the heading orientation specified by the location manager**. For more information, see the [headingOrientation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/headingOrientation) property in [CLLocationManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125).

It seems that you need to detect the device orientation and adjust values accordingly.